# Error:Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, androidx

I have integrated Firebase database in my Android application and getting error as below :

```
Error:Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub
```

You can check my gradle file as below :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.bestofapps.task.mycuteapp"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
        compileOptions {
            targetCompatibility 1.8
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation pri.support.appcompat
        implementation pri.support.design
        implementation pri.support.cardview
        implementation pri.support.recyclerview
        implementation pri.support.constraint

        //Lifecycle
        implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

        //Firebase

        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


        implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0@aar") {
            transitive = true
        }
        // Glide v4
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

        //Google Map
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


You can also check my build.gradle file as below : (Project Level)

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
apply from: './build_version.gradle'
```

I have also specified required Internet permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You can check all things are correct as above but am getting same error. Also checked by changing compileSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion.

I have also specified below two things in build.gradle file :

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = false
```

Please guide.

What might be the issue ?

Comment: You are using firebase libraries which require androidx migration. You can't use android support libraries.

Comment: that' why done as above : android.useAndroidX = true

Comment: may be it is not enough. Change your dependencies in build.gradle